# Jacuzzi tub hot water valve locked in place

Tags: bathtub, valve

We have one of those jacuzzi tubs in our bathroom and we'd like to use it.  When we bought the house, the inspector didn't catch the fact that the hot water valve is locked in place (cold water one works well).  I took it apart and everything looks fine to me (pics below).  I had a plumber come for other reasons and had him look at the valve, and he said that he doesn't know if it's "seized up or just stuck", and that if it's seized up and breaks somehow, he would have to break the tile to get to it, so it's probably not worth doing anything.  It's all Kohler but I don't know the exact model.

Is there anything I can try to do to fix it without risking damage?

Thanks

EDIT: adding image of the 'vent' near the tub
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are there shutoffs for this, maybe under the sink?

Comment: There’s no shutoff under the sink, but there’s a vent looking opening in the closet near it which might have something, probably for the electrical but I’ll check later today and reply back

Comment: @JACK: I added another picture of the vent opening from the side closet.  It looks like it's only electrical stuff for the tub with some water piping, but no visible water shut off there...

Comment: Once you've fixed the faucet ask a question on how to correct that electrical outlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have a useless tub taking up space, or you do what needs doing to fix it so it's useable. You may also have a claim against your "home inspector" for not catching it - that sort of thing is **exactly** why you wasted money to hire them, after all.

I would go in prepared to "break tile" (more likely I'd cut it out, actually - it's neater, and I'm not a plumber who does not care what sort of mess they make for some other trade to clean up) and I'd replace the broken tile with an access panel because having to break tile to access plumbing is *a really poor design choice made by idiots,* in my *not so humble* opinion.

Actually - Might look underneath, too, in case access from below could be done with less mess.

Comment: thanks, any tips about cutting it out? What tools would you use? I'm new to diy and home ownership.

Comment: Given it's tile: Probably an angle grinder with a dry diamond blade, while vacuuming the dust into a shop vac with a good filter. Depending what it's mounted on, you might need to use a different type of blade to get through (diamond blades don't cut wood very well at all, to say the least...)